Spectra Plugins (Wordpress) post masonary block not showing updates on live site
Post masonary  block of spectra plugin in wordpress is showing different colors and column overlapping on the live website.
Purged cache on the browser, wordpress editor and from cloudflare cache as well.
Check plugin incompatibility.
Am using generatepress theme - free version.
